# Ring of even integers

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

So I am given a ring of even integers.  It is an isomorphism of Z to R that is defined by f(x)=2x+4.  I am trying to find the O(R) and the 1(R).  I just set the function equal to 0 or 1 but apparently that is not the right thing to do in this case. Any rational as to what I am doing wrong or the correct way to think about it to set it up right?  Should you plug in 0 for 2 instead?

Comment: It seems like $f$ is not an isomorphism since $f(0)\neq 0$

Comment: the question says it is an isomorphism

Comment: @DaenerysNaharis it must not be a ring under usual addition and multiplication.

Comment: Oh yeah sorry, we suppose there are special rules for both in this problem

Comment: Your question is very hard to read. Is English your first language? If so, it might help to cite the problem word-for-word.

Comment: I find it pretty easy to read, and yes it is.

Comment: R is a ring of even integers with special rules for multiplication and addition.  Suppose that f : Z to R is an isomorphism that is defined by f(x) = 2x+4. Which integer in the ring is the identity and which is the zero (0(R)).

Comment: "Let $R$ be the set of even integers made into a ring with some addition and multiplication operations. Suppose $f:\Bbb Z\to R$ given by $x\mapsto 2x+4$ is a ring isomorphism. What are $0_R$ and $1_R$?" I'd have understood the problem instantly if you'd said this, for instance. The fact that multiple people have addressed a different form of question and you're spending time to explain yourself indicates that you were not clear to begin with in the original post.

Comment: alright ill make sure to do better next time

Answer (score 1):

The addition on $R$ has not been specified. If $f$ is to be an additive group isomorphism, then the addition $\oplus$ on $R$ has to be defined by $2s\oplus 2t=2s+2t-4$.

This is because $2s=f(s-2)$ and $2t=f(t-2)$. Since $f$ is an additive group isomorphism, we have $f((s-2)+(t-2)=2s\oplus 2t$. But 
$$f((s-2)+(t-2))=2s+2t-8+4=2s+2t-4.$$

Now the zero-element is not hard to identify. Call it $2z$. Then we want $2s\oplus 2z=2x$. That gives $2z=4$.

Do something similar to identify the  multiplication $\otimes$ on $R$.

Answer (score 0):

Since $f$ is an isomorphism, it sends $0$ to $0(R)$ and $1$ to $1(R)$.  So you're correct in setting the function equal to $0$ and $1$, respectively (that is, taking $f(0) = 4$ and $f(1) = 6$).

Let's find the units of $R$.  The units of $\mathbb Z$ are $-1$ and $1$, and since this is an isomorphism, $f$ maps units to units, so the units of $R$ are $f(-1) = 2$ and $f(1) = 6$

Comment: refer to my comment above with the whole question written out

Comment: @D-Man The answer still stands; just ignore the second paragraph.

Comment: this was a question on my test and I got this wrong.  I am pretty sure that my teacher said to just plug in 1 and 0 for x.

Comment: @D-Man then we are all in agreement.

Comment: so if i were to find the units I would set 2x+4=6 because we need xc=1(R)=6 where c is an integer in the ring? but that would give 2 and 1 are units but since it is only even integers it is just 2?

Comment: The fact that it is even integers is irrelevant.  The $1$ of $R$ is $f(1)$, since $f$ is an isomorphism.  $f(1) = 6$.  We don't solve any equations, (we only solve the equation $2x+4 = 6$ if we know $6$ is the $1(R)$ and we're trying to get the unity of $\mathbb Z$.

Comment: so 1 would be the unit... now just basing it off of my books definition of unit like i used above there needs to be ac=1(R), im just trying to relate this to the ring and its polynomial.  what would be the a and what would be the c based off the ring? or is that just looking at it in the wrong way?

Comment: @D-Man You're confusing unit with unity.  $1$ is a unity, whereas you're giving the definition of a unit.  $-1$ is a unit in the ring $\mathbb Z$ since $-1 \cdot -1 = 1$, but it is not *the* unity $1$.

Comment: yeah the question was what are the units in R?

Comment: @D-Man OK, the answer has been updated in light of this.

Comment: So just for the sake of my final exam I kind of want to look at the regular stuff for a ring of integers (units are 1,-1, identity is 1, zero is 0) and just know that because it is defined by a function that these will be different based off that function pretty much.

Comment: and also would you know how to find the special rules of addition and multiplication? i am given a hint that i should let a =f(x) and b=f(y).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14347/discussion-between-andrew-salmon-and-d-man)

Comment: i do not have the reputation unfortunately

Comment: I wouldn't have said 'set the function equal to 0' even with the clarification; to me, that implies solving the equation $f(x)=0$ for $x$.  Rather, a better phrase might be 'seeing where the function takes 0 to'.

Comment: Here's what I wrote up in chat:OK, so let's just go through this.
Let's use +' for addition in our new ring R and *' for multiplication.
f(a+b) = f(a) +' f(b)
2(a+b) + 4 = 2a+4 +' 2b+4
This doesn't give us any information yet--we want an expression for 2x +' 2y, so we have to make a change of variables first.
2x = 2a + 4, so 2x - 4 = 2a. Similarly, 2y - 4 = 2b.
So 2x-4 + 2y-4 + 4 = 2x +' 2y
And 2x +' 2y = 2x + 2y - 4
Do the same for *'